# Ввод только цифр в TextBox

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

Почему-то на эту тему упорно гуглится `e.Handled`, но я проверил - оно не работает. А вот `SuppressKeyPress` работает! Но есть один минус - я так заблокировал вообще все клавиши кроме цифр. В частности так не работает Backscape, а это уже проблема... Вопрос как заблокировать все кроме цифр и управляющих клавиш (типа Backscape, стрелочек и т.п.)?

```
System::Void textBox_KeyDown(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^ e) {
    if (e->KeyValue < '0' || e->KeyValue > '9') {
        e->SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, сделаете вы это. А потом выяснится, что мышкой можно редактировать содержимое. А потом пользователи вашей программы попросят добавить вставку в ваш текстбокс из буфера обмены (Ctrl+V)... Просто возьмите `NumericUpDown` вместо `TextBox`. ЗЫ: и не пишите на C++/CLI

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я бы и рад не писать на этом древнем Г, и использовать NumericUpDown, но это условия лабороторки (не моей даже). Думаю эти мелочи можно опустить.

Comment: Передайте преподу, который заставляет своих студентов писать приложения на С++/CLI, что он идиот. Покажите ему этот мой комментарий.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не могу)) Я просто фрилансю. В частности для студентов иногда))) Но я согласен с тем что это бред.

Comment: Кстати, C++/CLI вовсе не древнее г... Это хороший язык, уникальный и единственный в своём роде. Просто он не предназначен для написания приложений.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не слышал чтобы на нем что-то вообще писали... Ну да не важно. Можете хотя бы на C# придумать решение? Я переведу если что)

Comment: Инвертируйте ваш if, и установливайте значение false, после чего перед завершением ветвления, напишите return. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_KeyEventArgs_SuppressKeyPress

Comment: @mik.ov нет, это так не работает. Наоборот будет вводиться все кроме цифр